# Additional move constructor in pass by value function

Tags: c++11

I have a simple struct, that has all constructors defined.
It has an int variable, each constructor and assign operator prints address of *this, current value of int and a new value of int.
Move and copy assign operators and constructors also print adress of passed value.

```
#include <iostream>

struct X
{
    int val;
    void out(const std::string& s, int nv, const X* from = nullptr)
    {
        std::cout<<this<<"->"<<s<<": "<<val<<" ("<<nv<<")";
        if (from)
            std::cout<<", from: ["<<from<<"]";
        std::cout<<"\n";
    }

    X(){out("simple ctor X()",0); val = 0;}
    X(int v){out("int ctor X(int)", v);val = v; }
    X(const X& x){out("copy ctor X(X&)", x.val, &x);val = x.val; };
    X&operator = (const X& x){out("copy X::operator=()", x.val, &x); val = x.val; return *this;}
    ~X(){out("dtor ~X", 0);}
    X&operator = (X&& x){out("move X::operator(&&)", x.val, &x); val = x.val; return *this;}
    X(X&& x){out("move ctor X(&&x)", x.val, &x);val = x.val;}
};

X copy(X a){return a;}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    X loc{4};
    X loc2;
    std::cout<<"before copy\n";
    loc2 = copy(loc);
    std::cout<<"copy finish\n";
}
```

output:

> ```
> 0xffdf7278->int ctor X(int): 134523184 (4)
> 0xffdf727c->simple ctor X(): 134514433 (0)
> before copy
> 0xffdf7280->copy ctor X(X&): 1433459488 (4), from: [0xffdf7278]
> 0xffdf7284->move ctor X(&&x): 1433437824 (4), from: [0xffdf7280]
> 0xffdf727c->move X::operator(&&): 0 (4), from: [0xffdf7284]
> 0xffdf7284->dtor ~X: 4 (0)
> 0xffdf7280->dtor ~X: 4 (0)
> copy finish
> 0xffdf727c->dtor ~X: 4 (0)
> 0xffdf7278->dtor ~X: 4 (0)
> ```

What's the purpose of creating an additional object with (in this example) address 0xffdf7284?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the [copy elision rules from cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision), you can notice that there are two case where the compilers are required to omit the copy- and move- constructors of class objects *even if copy/move constructor and the destructor have observable side-effects* (which yours do, due to the printouts). The first is clearly irrelevant to this case. The second is

> In a function call, if the operand of a return statement is a prvalue and the return type of the function is the same as the type of that prvalue.

With the example given of:

```
T f() { return T{}; }
T x = f();
```

This seems more relevant, however, note that in your case, the operand of the `return` statement is *not a [prvalue](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category)*. So in this case, no mandatory elision applies.

The set of steps, when calling`loc2 = copy(loc);`, is as follows:

- `a` is copy-constructed from `loc`.
- The return value of the function is move-constructed from `a`.
- `loc2` is move-assigned from the return value.

Logically, a person could look at the code and deduce that fewer operations need to be done (in particular, when looking at `copy`, it's obvious that, logically, an assignment from `loc` to `loc2` is enough), but the compiler doesn't know that the purpose of your code isn't to generate the side effects (the printouts), and it is not breaking any rules here.

Comment: so, it is called to create appropriate prvalue?

Comment: @Guy-WithA-gum No exactly. Since it is not a prvalue, and all your methods have side effects, it moves it out, then calls the destructor. This simply does not involve prvalues at all.

Comment: so why it just doesn't return "a", why does it need a move-from-a-constructed-value

Comment: @Guy-WithA-gum Since your `a` destructor has a side effect, it needs to destruct it within the function. It also needs to return its content somehow. How can it do both? By first moving out its content.

Comment: @Guy-WithA-gum Not quite. On the contrary. A move constructor is required to leave the object in a valid state for destruction.

Comment: i guessed it would be like this:  
`before copy  
0xffdf7280->copy ctor X(X&): 1433459488 (4), from: [0xffdf7278]   //copy for pass by value  
0xffdf727c->move X::operator(&&): 0 (4), from: [0xffdf7280]//move from created copy  
0xffdf7280->dtor ~X: 4 (0)//destruct created copy  
copy finish`

Comment: So, IIUC, you're asking a bit differently again about the need for `0xffdf7284`. The problem is with `0xffdf7280` (local `a`). OTOH, the compiler can't know that the purpose of this code isn't to print out using its dtor in `copy`. So it has to retain this as a local copy - one that is destructed *before* the move assignment. OTOH, it analyzes that if it's destructed in the function, its content is invisible out of it. Hence, it first moves out its content, then destructs (and prints, which is what it's after). That is what's creating `0xffdf7284`, which just had content moved in/out of it.

Comment: but destructors of both copied (created by copy ctor) and moved (created by move ctor) objects invoked after move assignment... Why it can't just move data from copied object and destruct it after move assignment... Why it needs to create another temporary object...

Comment: @Guy-WithA-gum But it's not just the order. Suppose it would have a (modifiable) string, which inside the function you'd set to "done with copy", and expect it to print it (for debugging or whatever). That's the thing with side effects - the compiler is very conservative about it; it has to be.

Comment: it's worth noting that elision from lvalues also exists, but copy elision is explicitly disabled when returning a function parameter (simply because, on the caller side, parameter and return value live at different memory  locations or registers and cannot be unified).